# How to change data value in a column if it match with flag=1

Tags: sql

So assume there are 2 cols Name and Flag. I want to change the name of the data which have flag=1.

This is the table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LILzV.png)

And this is what i want.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPZWj.png)

I have first created a flag according to some condition. Now im not able to fig out the next move.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

```
update TableName
set name = 'zumba'
where flag = 1
```

Edit: as pointed out by jarlh, single quotes are the correct syntax

Comment: right, thx for the correction